# "Суд удаляется для ПОСТАНОВЛЕНИЯ приговора"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, лексика, значение-слов

В популярной передаче НТВ "Суд присяжных" постоянно звучат специфические в судебной практике фразы, к которым с грамматической точки зрения придраться трудно. Но вот одна из них вызывает сомнения, когда судья после вердикта присяжных каждый раз заявляет: "Суд удаляется для ПОСТАНОВЛЕНИЯ приговора". Корректно ли выделенное существительное превращать в глагол, который в словарях в таком виде и не зафиксирован? Большая просьба не ограничиться констатацией типа корректно или некорректно, а дать более или менее обстоятельный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос интересный, хотя вы и намудрили тут. Постановление - не глагол никаким образом.

Если по сути, то я считаю, что грамматической ошибки тут нет. Самое большое, что можно принять, что это фразеологический оборот (устоявшееся выражение), связанный с устаревшем значением слова "постановление" - действия, а не результата. Таких оборотов полно в юридической лингвистической практике, основанной на языке XVIII-XIX века, а его-то уж безграмотным никак нельзя назвать. Беда в том, что в первые годы и десятилетия советской власти не очень грамотные во всех смыслах "реформаторы" начали бороться с формулировками, вводя свои собственные и разрушая понятийное поле существовавших. Видимо тогда-то "постановление" и перестало быть процессом вынесения официального решения и стало его результатом. Аналогичное произошло, например, со словами "заседание", "присутствие", "собрание". В разной правда степени, но все они потеряли одно из основных значений - действия по производящему глаголу.

Спорить и тем более что-то меня считаю бесполезным и даже вредным. Пусть так и остаётся - в рамках официального языка, разумеется.

Answer (score 1):

Глагол "постановлять", связанный с существительным в таком значении, фиксируется словарями (Ушаков, Ефремова и др. словари), а в качестве переходного применяется в деловой практике (преимущественно, юридической). Например: "Приговор постановляется председательствующим в порядке, установленном главой 39 настоящего Кодекса..." (УПК РФ, Статья 351. Постановление приговора). Распространён и оборот "суд постановляет (,что)...".

Подборка словарей:
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/fre_rus/111009/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: *Глагол "постановлять", связанный с существительным... * - А разве в этом глаголе кто-то сомневался? Вопросы вызывает только ***отглагольное существительное*** в значении "действие по этому глаголу".

Comment: Это действительно отглагольное существительное, ср.: "Суд вынес постановление..."

Comment: @behemotus В глаголе co значением действия сомневается сам автор вопроса: "Корректно ли выделенное существительное превращать в глагол... ". Можно и перефразировать вопрос: при данном употреблении существительного суд удаляется "постановление готовить" или "постановлять" что-то? Ответ: второе. Поэтому прояснено значение исходного глагола.